# Even Function Fourier Expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm having a bit of trouble completing a homework question of mine. I am supposed to expand an equation using Fourier and then graph said equation using Matlab. And no matter what I do the graph of the original equation and the Fourier equation never match up at all.

The question given is:

Given $f(x)= \begin{cases}
L/2, & 0 \le x \le L/2 \\
x - L/2, & L/2 \lt x \le L
\end{cases}$

expand $f(x)$ in terms of the functions $\{1, \cos(\frac{n{\pi}x}{L})\}, \; n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, \; \text{on } 0 \le x \le L$.

By the looks of it, it wants me to turn it into an even function and to only calculate $a_0$ and $a_n$.

If I do this the fourier series ends up being the following:

$$F(x)= \frac{3L}{8}+ \frac{2L}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}[1-(-1)^{n+1}]\cos(\frac{n{\pi}x}{L})$$

If I put that into Matlab and graph it, it will come out as this: [f(x) vs F(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3lKr.png). The blue line is the original equation, while the red line is the Fourier expansion. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv558.png) is the Matlab code I'm using. As you can see these are nothing alike.

Can someone smarter than me try to pinpoint my mistake and help me understand?

Comment: How many terms of the Fourier expansion are you using?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Apparently, at least 100, since the plot doesn't look like an analytic even function, despite being created from cosines. @ Bradley, please show how you derive your $F$. It doesn't look correct.

Comment: Here is my working: [Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKdIQ.jpg), 
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDSkC.jpg).

For the number of terms of the Fourier expansion, I just used whatever amount I set in Matlab (started with 100). No matter how many I did it never looked like what the actual solution is.

Comment: The cosine terms all have $0$ endpoint derivatives, which is also true of any finite sum of such terms. That doesn't match with your graph at all.